# Twitter4j: how to get twit url from status?

Tags: java, twitter

I am using twitter4j-3.0.5 on Windows.

When new status arrives to the StatusListener.[onStatus()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusListener.html#onStatus%28twitter4j.Status%29) method, I would like to print out it's URL but I don't find any appropriate method. status.[getURLEntities()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/EntitySupport.html#getURLEntities%28%29) is always empty, even tough if I look at the json passed to the client, the url field is not empty and contains valid URL.
I just don't know how to get this value from java.

Please advise.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `getURLEntities()` method returns any URLs in the content of the tweet itself, not the URL *of* the tweet.

Fortunately the URL of a tweet is in the following format:

`https://twitter.com/[screen name of user]/status/[id of status]`

So you can get the URL of a status with this code:

```java
Status status;
String url= "https://twitter.com/" + status.getUser().getScreenName() 
    + "/status/" + status.getId();
System.out.println(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

URL can be exposed by 2 ways.

- giving the twitter link
- giving the website link which is tweeted.

## Sample Example:

```
package com.twitter.example;

import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.URLEntity;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        ConfigurationBuilder cf = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cf.setOAuthConsumerKey("OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cf.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        // get username and status
        List<Status> statusList = twitter.getHomeTimeline();

        int i = 0;
        for (Status status : statusList) {
            i++;
            String url = "https://twitter.com/" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + "/status/" + status.getId();
            System.out.println("Twitter URL:"+url);

            URLEntity[] urls = status.getURLEntities();
            for(URLEntity urlEntity : urls) {
                url = urlEntity.getURL();
                System.out.println("Website link URL in the tweet: "+url);
            }
            if (i == 1)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

## Output:

> Twitter URL:https://twitter.com/CulturalGM/status/966308069884952577
>
> Website link URL in the tweet: https://websitelink